# Struts2 maven archetype

Tags: maven, struts2

I'm trying to set up a Struts2 project using the **struts2-archetype-blank** archetype as pointed out in Struts wiki.

```
mvn archetype:generate -B  -DgroupId=tutorial -DartifactId=tutorial -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-blank  -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.8
```

However I get the following error:

```
[INFO] Archetype repository missing. Using the one from [org.apache.struts:strus2-archetype-blank:2.3.8] found in catalog remote
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2-archetype-
lank/2.1.8/struts2-archetype-blank-2.1.8.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE<br/>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
[INFO] Total time: 5.829s<br/>
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 09 10:10:26 CET 2013<br/>
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/17M<br/>
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------<br/>
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:.2:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist <br/>(org.apache.struts:struts2-archetype-blank:2.1.8) -> [Help 1]<br/>
[ERROR]
```

Do I need a particular repository in my Maven config to use this archetype?

Comment: A typo? Look at the error message, there is [...:strus..] instead of struts. At least I found it here: https://repository.apache.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~~struts2-archetype-blank~~~

Comment: Adrian, this should be an answer IMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use just

```
mvn archetype:generate -B  -DgroupId=tutorial -DartifactId=tutorial -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.struts -DarchetypeArtifactId=struts2-archetype-blank
```

without

> -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.8

to use the latest version available (currently 2.3.8), the 2.1.8 is not available in the central repo.